# How to remove MultiBrowser in Mountain Lion Mac OS X

Tags: browser

I installed MultiBrowser from this location: https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33861/multibrowser. Now I am trying to remove it from my Macbook. I have Mountain Lion. I deleted the application from /Applications but the icon is still showing in the System Preferences > Other section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are "Preference Panes". Only proceed if the application provider did not supply uninstallation instructions.

---

If installed at the root, you can find them here:
    `/Library/PreferencePanes`

If installed for a particular user, you can find them here (hidden folder):
    `~/Library/PreferencePanes`

Delete the associated `.prefPane` file and this should remove the offending application pane from System Preferences. You may need to restart or log off/on.

---

**[UPDATE]** - You can also right-click (ctrl + click) the icon in System Preferences.